# magento 2 How to add new column in order csv export

Tags: magento2, csv, order-grid

magento 2 How to add new column qty ordered in order csv export. and coumn should not be visible in the grid

Answer (score 0):

**It can  possible.**

Create **After plugin** on `\Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider::getFields`.

**Original Method:**

> `public function getFields(UiComponentInterface $component)`

**Create di.xml at `app/code/{Vendorname}/{YourModulename}/etc/adminhtml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider">
        <plugin name="add_extra_column_to_order_grid"
                disabled="false"
                sortOrder="10"
                type="{Vendorname}\{YourModulename}\Plugin\Model\MetadataProvider"/>
    </type>   
</config>
```

**and Plugin class:**

```
<?php


namespace {Vendorname}\{YourModulename}\Plugin\Model;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;

class MetadataProvider
{
    public function afterGetFields(
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $subject,
        $result,
        UiComponentInterface $component
    ){
        if($component->getName() !== 'sales_order_grid'){
            return $result;
        }
        /**
         * add new column
         */
        if(!empty($result)){
            $result[] = 'yourNewColumn';
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function afterGetHeaders(
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $subject,
        $result,
        UiComponentInterface $component
    ){
        if($component->getName() !== 'sales_order_grid'){
            return $result;
        }
        /**
         * add new column
         */
        if(!empty($result)){
            $result[] = 'yourNewColumnLabel';
        }
        return $result;       
    }   
}
```

**Note that code is tested, just given based on idea**.